# How to subset data as per account in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to subset data as per one column In R using for loop. All I want to look at the different accounts in different datasets.
In the data attached I want to subset using first variable which is Account.
Code:-

```
for i in 1:Length(Data$Account)
{

data<- subset(Train, Train$Account==i)

df<-data
}


Account Sales   Date
1   10  1/1/2017
2   21  2/1/2017
3   23  3/1/2017
4   24  4/1/2017
4   24  5/1/2017
5   25  6/1/2017
4   25  7/1/2017
5   266 8/1/2017
6   556 9/1/2017
7   346 10/1/2017
5   42  11/1/2017
3   246 12/1/2017
2   356 1/1/2018
```

My requirement should return something like this for Account 4:-

```
Account Sales   Date
4   24  4/1/2017
4   24  5/1/2017
4   25  7/1/2017
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar for sharing this. But the data I have is huge. So a for loo where I can iterate it and write the data into new file would be preferable

Comment: Try the `split` function in R. In your case it should be: `split(data, data$Account)`

Comment: Will split subset data as per account in iteration?

Comment: Why don't you try it first? It is not clear what your objective is. Do you want subset of your complete data.frame for each unique account value? What are you going to do with the subset? `split` will split your data.frame by the unique values of `Account` variable and return a `list` of data.frames.

Comment: Tushar, I am writing a function where I want my base data to be divided in groups based on Account. and should be stored in a dataframe. So that I can use that dataframe to perform some functions.  This is why I am using loop so that everytime function is performed only on stored subset data in dataframe

Comment: So, you should use `split` in that case. It will return a list of data.frames which you can iterate through lapply/sapply and apply the required function. The approach you are taking will lead to creation of a lot of data.frame objects.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will create multiple datasets with columns `Sales` and `Date` and the name will be the corresponding `Account`. The csv files will be saved in your currect working directory.

```
df = read.table(text = "
Account Sales   Date
1   10  1/1/2017
2   21  2/1/2017
3   23  3/1/2017
4   24  4/1/2017
4   24  5/1/2017
5   25  6/1/2017
4   25  7/1/2017
5   266 8/1/2017
6   556 9/1/2017
7   346 10/1/2017
5   42  11/1/2017
3   246 12/1/2017
2   356 1/1/2018
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)


library(tidyverse)

# create a dataset where data are split by account
# (print is not actually needed, but just to show you how it looks like)
df2 = df %>% group_by(Account) %>% nest() %>% print()

# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#     Account             data
#       <int>           <list>
#   1       1 <tibble [1 x 2]>
#   2       2 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#   3       3 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#   4       4 <tibble [3 x 2]>
#   5       5 <tibble [3 x 2]>
#   6       6 <tibble [1 x 2]>
#   7       7 <tibble [1 x 2]>

# map those 2 columns to a function that writes csv files
map2(df2$data, df2$Account,~ write.csv(.x, file=paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this pretty easily with the dplyr package:

Your condition you want is ACCOUNT == 4

There are two ways to go about this with the package; either SELECT or FILTER:

Select will explicitly give you data for the columns you ask for (or want to remove with a -column_name in the function)

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%

  select(data, ACCOUNT, SALES, DATE) %>% 

    filter(ACCOUNT == 4)
```

Now this is a single conditional statement, I'll add a multi-condition just in case it comes in handy later on and hopefully so some other people can see this when they need help with a similar problem.

Multi-conditions use the same operators you can imagine, || or && for java and in R it's just | or &. | = or statements, & = and statements. Let's say for argument sake you wanted to see how your accounts are doing. Let's say you wanted to see your monthly sales data only or you wanted to see last week's performance. To do this you'll need to first specify the account number and then we do a date condition like so.

```
data %>%

select(data, ACCOUNT, SALES, DATE) %>% 

   filter(ACCOUNT == 4 & DATE == 7/1/2017)
```

after this is all done it's just a simple procedure of using vectors to save your data in the R environment i.e. data <- data %>%.....